# multiple email accounts as sender

Tags: email, smtp

How to send an email from multiple email accounts at the same time to a single account?
Means we can enter more than one email address in the from section of new email window.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, why would there be multiple senders? Are you actually looking for having multiple fields in "Reply-To" header? Haven't tried, but that could work.

Comment: Actually one of my client needs service of sending emails from multiple accounts to a single account atvthe same time for his business purpose

Comment: You didn't really answer anything, you just said "business purpose", which is really not any explanation at all.

Answer (score 1):

The Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) don't allow for multiple FROM addresses or at least you can do what you want but the SMTP relay server  will most likely return a 5xx code (Error).

As mentioned in your comment section, you can take use of the "Reply-To" header. This is what will be used when clicking reply by the receiver if the E-Mail client supports it. It's used typically in simple group message setups that don't have fully functional lists etc.

If you want to use the Reply-To header with multiple e-mail addresses your want to separate them with the expected delimiter that your SMTP server supports. Most common is either "comma" or "semicolon".

E.g

```
Reply-To: email1@dom.tld, email2@dom.tld, email3@dom.tld
```

I hope you get it worked out, but short answer is "NO" - SMTP don't support multiple FROM addresses. It also don't make sense to do so as the original sender can always only be one source :)

Comment: Last time I checked, Microsoft had decided in their wisdom to ignore `Reply-To:`

Comment: @tripleee just tested it in MS Outlook and Office 365 (OWA) worked fine. But I know that there can be problems with auto reply not always using the Reply-To header. What Microsoft clients are you referring to ?

Comment: It's been a while, but Outlook (and I think the old Outlook Express) used to have a problem with this.